# Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError after uploading Android application to google play

Tags: android

after uploading application to Google Play, pre launch report is executed and I can see crash that I am not able to reproduce, stack trace below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method m$2(JJ)J in class Lj$/util/function/IntConsumer$-CC; or its super classes (declaration of 'j$.util.function.IntConsumer$-CC' appears in /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-eRBTmbJC17tDrJVqQd45Aw==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
       at j$.time.Duration.ofSeconds(:3)
       at j$.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.<clinit>(:311)
       at j$.time.temporal.ChronoField.<clinit>(:7)
       at j$.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.<clinit>(:20)
       at j$.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.<clinit>()
       at j$.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()
```

It fails on line:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DB_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
```

app details, I am using:

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
Gradle 8.0.2
compileSdkVersion 33
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 33
```

Any advices what can be wrong or how to reproduce it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to narrow down the issue.
The problem is with gradle vs. android gradle plugin.
When I used latest available versions of gradle (7.5.1) and agp (7.4.2) it crashes on line:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DB_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
```

with exception:

```
Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method m$3(JJ)J in class Lj$/util/function/IntConsumer$-CC; or its super classes (declaration of 'j$.util.function.IntConsumer$-CC' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)
  at j$.time.Duration.ofSeconds
  at j$.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.<clinit>
  at j$.time.temporal.ChronoField.<clinit>
  at j$.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.<clinit>
  at j$.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.<clinit>
  at j$.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern
```

Versions 7.3.3 (Gradle) and 7.2.2 (AGP) are working fine. I have raised a bug:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/274626810
Please track for the solution there.